# Can the privileges page for trusted users list answer deletion guidelines?

Tags: feature-request, support, privileges, deleted-answers, trusted-user

[`/privileges/trusted-user`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) does not explain when it is best to apply the *delete answers* privilege.

Where can I find guidelines about deleting answers? Can these be added to the privilege page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explanation on [the privilege page for moderator tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), which is the first time you get deletion powers. I'm not sure what would be served by repeating it.

Comment: What about deleting answers?

Comment: @TomWijsman When you reach that level, you should have a good understanding of how the system works, which means your 'call' on what to vote to delete is hopefully sound. If you think people _other_ than and including you would be embarrassed to have the answer on the site and it can't be saved with a minor edit, then it probably needs to be deleted. If it's a pet peeve, or if you're unsure, just move onto the next one.

Comment: When it doubt, don't fix it.